# HTML DOMParser in Laravel

Tags: laravel, domparser

I want to get content of 'p' tag from site http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20191121/k10012185811000.html

p tag has 'content--summary' & 'content--summary-more' class, but I can't get data
this my code

```
        $htmlurl = 'http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20191121/k10012185811000.html';
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTMLFile($htmlurl);
        $data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

Can you tell me how to get text please. I'm using laravel 6.2

Comment: try this package https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$htmlurl = 'http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20191121/k10012185811000.html';
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($htmlurl);
$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach( $data as $p ) {
    echo $p->textContent; // Print out content of <p> tags
    echo $p->getAttribute('class'); // Print out attribute's <p> classes
}
```

Comment: Did you get error message? Or it just can't find the tag <p> and print out the empty result? I open site URL that you are trying to parse, they work with JS framework and download content via AJAX requests represented in JSON, in this case DOMDocument wouldn't work. You should try use JSON parser.